# SQLDataReader is not reading the second table returned by stored procedure

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am using the below code to read and populate two C# objects using datareader. But I am unable to read the second table.

```
using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
     var sqlCommand = "usp_GetFileListforPurging";
     var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, myConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
     cmd.CommandTimeout = Timeout == 0 ? 30 : Timeout * 30;
     myConnection.Open();
     using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
          _tableAllSet.Load(reader); //read's the first table
          reader.NextResult(); //But this is returning false, although my SP is returning two tables
          _tableTrueSet.Load(reader);
     }
     myConnection.Close();
}
```

Below is the snip of data returned by SP

[image]

Comment: Could you show your stored procedure?

Comment: what is `_tableAllSet` ? a `DataTable`? or a `DataSet`? or...? (note: if either: *why* are you using `DataTable`/`DataSet`? they are **horribly** over-used, and are a very bad fit for most scenarios)

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, it's a datatable. What should I use then?

Comment: @HarshSharma any reason not to just use a regular class, and a `List<T>` of that? Tools like EF or Dapper make this a breeze, and it is **much** more efficient than `DataTable`, and easier to work with

Comment: @StepUp SP is very lengthy, however, I have included snip of data returned by SP.

Comment: @MarcGravell ok sir, I will use it. But do you have any suggestion for the above question?

Comment: "multiple result sets" is an option in the connection string. This might help but I am not sure. Also I don't really know how to handle multiple result sets. The docs might help here. So its not an answer but a comment :)

Comment: @DanielSchmid you're talking about MARS - that a *completely different* thing, allowing multiple **unrelated** commands to be executed concurrently on the same connection; you don't need any connection-string parameters for a regular multi-result command

Comment: @HarshSharma for an example of using Dapper with multiple results: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#multiple-results - note that to invoke an SP, you'd need to add `commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure` to the `QueryMultiple` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataTable.Load` already progresses the reader, at the end - essentially:

```cs
        if (!reader.IsClosed && !reader.NextResult())
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
```

([citation from reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs#L4480-L4482))

So: don't call `NextResult` yourself when using `Load`, as that will cause the second grid to be skipped.